# custom comments on specific post type

Tags: custom-post-types, comments, conditional-tags

I have a custom post type called debate and I want to create some custom fields just on this post type. 
So, I have this code:

```
function debate_comment_fields( $fields ) {

   if( is_singular( 'debate' ) ) {

    unset($fields['url']);
     unset($fields['author']);
     unset($fields['email']);

    $fields['options'] = '<p class="comment-form-options"><label for="options">' . __( 'I want to' ) . '</label>' .
        '<input id="first" name="category" type="radio" value="' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'agree', true) .'" />'. 
        '<input id="second" name="category" type="radio" value="' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'disagree', true) .'" /></p>';

         return $fields;

   }
  } 
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','debate_comment_fields');
```

Everything is ok on my custom post type, but on the default blog post type the author,email and url are not displayed.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, alter the single-debate.php and call a custom comment template using [comment_template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template) with a parameter, representing your custom comment template.

```
<?php
// If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() )
    comments_template('custom-comments.php');
?>
```

Comment: thanks for this, but is not relevant for what I'm asking for...

Comment: in functions.php the line `if( is_singular( 'debate' ) ) {` does not make sense. its only for the template that you are viewing see[is_singular](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular). first register the custom fields in functions php. then show them in the template.

Comment: ok, do you have any suggestion on how can I make this work just on that specific post type ?

Comment: why not check out the plugin above, it seems that would be easiest. i can not test it now unfortunately. but there are many tutorials, see maybe this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064908/how-do-i-add-custom-fields-to-my-custom-post-type-in-wordpress-3)

Comment: I don't think you understand exactly what I need. That thread is about something else, the plugin is also about something different. All I need is just a function,conditional to display those custom comment fields on a specific custom type which is already created.

Comment: your questions are definately answered in the tutorials cited in the answers on the above thread.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can not find something related, anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: i want to help you now, can you again specify what you need. Your custom post type already has a custom field? you just want to display the content of it? how did you define the custom field? Where?

Comment: I have created the custom post type everything is working fine, what I need is to output that code which is posted in the question to work only inside a specific custom post type which in my case is called "debate". I don't need to create custom fields neither custom post types because these are already created. My question is how can I have different comment fields on a specific post type.

Comment: It will work if I copy and paste the code in custom-comments.php and call it ? Or do you have to create other code ?

Comment: it will work with the code above only in the template and a custom comments template. copy the code from comments.php and alter it.

Comment: I've added inside my question the code from my comments.php file. The problem is I don't know where I can add the code. Can you have a look? thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11313/discussion-between-user9-and-alecs)

Comment: I'm in the chatroom...

Comment: Added additional info to my  question ...